# Opening/printing TIFF files in VB.NET Visual Studio 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, tiff

I'm trying to use my existing application to open [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) files for clients and staff in order to print or view the reports that we have scanned into our server. Unfortunately I have been unable to find a free, preferably open source library or wrapper for a library that will work in VB.NET running through Visual Studio 2005.

Is there any open source/free implementations of this that I could adopt in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FreeImage library, downloadable from [FreeImage.net](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).

To link it, add a reference to your project to the DLL contained in:

```
FreeImage/Wrapper/FreeImage.NET/CS/Bin
```

Once it is linked, import FreeImageAPI into your class.

then, declare your variables:

```
Dim pageCount As Integer
Dim imagePage As FreeImageAPI.FIBITMAP
Dim tiffImage As FreeImageAPI.FIMULTIBITMAP

tiffImage = FreeImageAPI.FreeImage.OpenMultiBitmapEx(ImagePath)
pageCount = FreeImage.GetPageCount(tiffImage)
imagePage = FreeImage.LockPage(tiffImage, 0)
imgMain.Image = FreeImage.GetBitmap(scaledImage)
imgMain.Show()
```

This will return the first page of a multi-page tiff file. To get each page afterwards,

```
FreeImage.UnlockPage(tiffImage, imagePage, false)
imagePage = FreeImage.LockPage(tiffImage, newPageNum)
```